# When running test unable to locat variable

Tags: blockchain, python, testing

the Code executes properly, although when I attempt to run a test it fails. It appears to me as if, when the test calls the deploy function which calls should call Lottery.sol contract and run getEntranceFee for the entrance_fee variable is unbable to.

The test code

```
from brownie import Lottery, accounts, config, network
from scripts.deploy_lottery import deploy_lottery
from web3 import Web3


def test_get_entrance_fee():
    # arrange
    lottery = deploy_lottery()
    # act
    # if 2000 eth to  usd
    # usdEntryFee is 50
    # 2000/1 == 50/x == 0.025
    expected_entrance_fee = Web3.toWei(0.025, "ether")
    print(expected_entrance_fee)
    entrance_fee = lottery.getEntranceFee()
    print(entrance_fee)
    # assert
    assert expected_entrance_fee == entrance_fee
```

```
PS D:\GDrive\NFTs\Deployment\Training\Solidity\smartcontract_lottery> brownie test -k test_get_entrance_fee
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.17.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum

====================================================================================================== test session starts ======================================================================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.9.9, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: D:\GDrive\NFTs\Deployment\Training\Solidity\smartcontract_lottery
plugins: eth-brownie-1.17.2, hypothesis-6.27.3, forked-1.3.0, xdist-1.34.0, web3-5.25.0
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Attached to local RPC client listening at '127.0.0.1:8545'...

tests\test_lottery_unit.py F                                                                                                                                                                                               [100%]

=========================================================================================================== FAILURES ============================================================================================================ 
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________ test_get_entrance_fee _____________________________________________________________________________________________________

    def test_get_entrance_fee():
        # arrange
        lottery = deploy_lottery()
        # act
        # if 2000 eth to  usd
        # usdEntryFee is 50
        # 2000/1 == 50/x == 0.025
        expected_entrance_fee = Web3.toWei(0.025, "ether")
        print(expected_entrance_fee)
>       entrance_fee = lottery.getEntranceFee()
E       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getEntranceFee'

tests\test_lottery_unit.py:15: AttributeError
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
Deployed!
Deployed lottery!
25000000000000000
======================================================================================================= warnings summary ======================================================================================================== 
C:\Users\zenadmin\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\main.py:44
  C:\Users\zenadmin\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\main.py:44: BrownieEnvironmentWarning: Development network has a block height of 14
    warnings.warn(

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
==================================================================================================== short test summary info ==================================================================================================== 
FAILED tests/test_lottery_unit.py::test_get_entrance_fee - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getEntranceFee'
================================================================================================= 1 failed, 1 warning in 2.36s ==================================================================================================
```

deploy_lottery

```
from scripts.helpful_scripts import get_account, get_contract, fund_with_link
from brownie import Lottery, network, config
import time


def deploy_lottery():
    account = get_account()
    lottery = Lottery.deploy(
        get_contract("eth_usd_price_feed").address,
        get_contract("vrf_coordinator").address,
        get_contract("link_token").address,
        config["networks"][network.show_active()]["fee"],
        config["networks"][network.show_active()]["keyhash"], {
            "from": account},
        publish_source=config["networks"][network.show_active()].get(
            "verify", False),
    )
    print("Deployed lottery!")


def start_lottery():
    account = get_account()
    lottery = Lottery[-1]
    starting_tx = lottery.startLottery({"from": account})
    starting_tx.wait(1)
    print("The lottery has started!")


def enter_lottery():
    account = get_account()
    lottery = Lottery[-1]
    cost = lottery.getEntranceFee()
    value = lottery.getEntranceFee() + 100000000
    print(cost)
    print(value)
    tx = lottery.enter({"from": account, "value": value})
    tx.wait(1)
    print("You entered the lottery!")


def end_lottery():
    account = get_account()
    lottery = Lottery[-1]
    # fund the contract
    # the end of lottery
    tx = fund_with_link(lottery.address)
    tx
    ending_transaction = lottery.endLottery({"from": account})
    ending_transaction.wait(1)
    time.sleep(60)
    print(f"{lottery.recentWinner()} is the new winner!")


def main():
    deploy_lottery()
    start_lottery()
    enter_lottery()
    end_lottery()
```

and finally lottery.sol
*** note i had an issue with enter_lottery function where it was unable to get the lottery state to explicatly set the variable before it checks it.***

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol";

contract Lottery is VRFConsumerBase, Ownable {
    address payable[] public players;
    uint256 public usdEntryFee;
    address payable public recentWinner;
    uint256 public randomness;

    AggregatorV3Interface internal ethUsdPriceFeed;
    enum LOTTERY_STATE {
        OPEN,
        CLOSED,
        CALCULATING_WINNER
    }
    LOTTERY_STATE public lottery_state;
    uint256 public fee;
    bytes32 public keyhash;

    // 0
    // 1
    // 2

    constructor(
        address _priceFeedAddress,
        address _vrfCoordinator,
        address _link,
        uint256 _fee,
        bytes32 _keyhash
    ) public VRFConsumerBase(_vrfCoordinator, _link) {
        usdEntryFee = 50 * (10**18);
        ethUsdPriceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(_priceFeedAddress);
        lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.CLOSED;
        fee = _fee;
        keyhash = _keyhash;
        // LOTTERY_STATE.CLOSED could also be written as 1
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        // $50 min
        // lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.OPEN;
        lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.OPEN;
        require(lottery_state == LOTTERY_STATE.OPEN);
        require(msg.value >= getEntranceFee(), "Not Enough ETH!");
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function getEntranceFee() public view returns (uint256) {
        // Store entrance fee somewhere when contract deployed
        (, int256 price, , , ) = ethUsdPriceFeed.latestRoundData();
        uint256 adjustedPrice = uint256(price) * 10**10; // 18 decimals
        //$50, $2000 eth
        // 50/2000
        // 50 * 10000 / 2000
        uint256 costToEnter = (usdEntryFee * 10**18) / adjustedPrice;
        return costToEnter;
    }

    function startLottery() public {
        require(
            lottery_state == LOTTERY_STATE.CLOSED,
            "Can't start a new lottery yet! "
        );
        lottery_state == LOTTERY_STATE.OPEN;
    }

    function endLottery() public onlyOwner {
        // uint256(
        //     keccack256(
        //         abi.encodedPacked(
        //             nonce, // predictable aka transaction number
        //             msg.sender // predictable
        //             block.difficulty, // difficulty can actually be manipulated by miners!
        //             block.timestamp // predictable
        //         )
        //     )
        // ) % players.length;
        // *** Chainlink VRF only way to get a random number
        lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.CALCULATING_WINNER;
        bytes32 requestId = requestRandomness(keyhash, fee);
        // once requests random number, must also now return it
    }

    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _randomness)
        internal
        override
    {
        require(
            lottery_state == LOTTERY_STATE.CALCULATING_WINNER,
            "You are not there yet!"
        );
        require(_randomness > 0, "random-not-found");
        // 7 players
        // 22 as random number
        // 22 % 7 , remainder 1
        // 7 * 3 = 21
        // 7 * 4 = 28
        uint256 indexOfWinner = _randomness % players.length;
        recentWinner = players[indexOfWinner];
        recentWinner.transfer(address(this).balance);
        // reset
        players = new address payable[](0);
        lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.CLOSED;
        randomness = _randomness;
    }
}
```

been trying to figure this out the past few days and am stumped. Is it a glitch? as the code does run, but test fails?

Comment: You are assigning `lottery = deploy_lottery()` but the function `deploy_lottery` doesn't return anything. Can you print the returned value?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you got this fix but in case someone else needs it.
on your deploy_lottery.py you need to return the lottery variable.

on your deploy_lottery.py you need to return the lottery variable.

```
def deploy_lottery(): 
    account = get_account() 
    lottery = Lottery.deploy( get_contract("eth_usd_price_feed").address,
    get_contract("vrf_coordinator").address, 
    get_contract("link_token").address, 
    config["networks"][network.show_active()]["fee"], 
    config["networks"][network.show_active()]["keyhash"], 
    { "from": account}, publish_source=config["networks"][network.show_active()].get( "verify", False), ) 
    print("Deployed lottery!")
    return lottery
```